# Tensorflow CIFAR10 slows down every 100th step

Tags: tensorflow

#### System information

- **OS**: Linux Ubuntu 16.04
- **TensorFlow installed from**: Have tried both binary and source
- **TensorFlow version**: 1.4.0-19-ga52c8d9, 1.4.1
- **Python version**: 2.7.12
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: 8.0.61
- **Hardware**: GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti (11GB), RAM: 64GB, CPU: Intel i7-6850K
- **Exact command to reproduce**: python cifar10_train.py

#### Describe the problem

The [CIFAR10 Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn) seems to have a few odd patterns when it comes to the number of examples per second it can compute:
 - Step 0 is extremely slow 
 - Every 100th step is significantly slow 
 - The step after a really slow step is either a little slow or average
 - The next 10-30 steps after that are slightly boosted (faster than average)
 - The rest of the steps are average speed

I'm hoping for (in order of importance):
 - An explanation and fix for every 100th step being so slow
 - An explanation and instructions showing me how to make every step run at the boosted speed (the speed shortly after a slow step)
 - An explanation and fix for the slow 0th and 1st step

I can't find any additional logging or processing that happens on every 100th step. Could it be `tf.train.MonitoredSession`?

#### Reproducible:

- when training on CPU rather than GPU
- independent of batch size
- on MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)

#### Hardware utilization:

1. Average:

   - CPU: 82-84%
   - GPU: 70-85%
   - RAM: 3.7GB
2. Every 100th step:

   - CPU: 9%
   - GPU: 0%
   - RAM: 3.7GB
3. Boosted after slow step:

   - GPU: 92%
   - CPU: 82-84%
   - RAM: 3.7GB
4. Idle:

   - CPU: 1%
   - GPU: 0%
   - RAM: 1.6GB

*Overall CPU and RAM usage (clearly showing CPU trough every 100 steps)*:
[image: Overall CPU and RAM usage]

#### Logs excerpt [(full logs)](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/files/1635342/terminalOutput.txt):

```
step 0: (587.3 examples/sec; 6.974 sec/batch)
step 1: (22630.6 examples/sec; 0.181 sec/batch)
step 2: (36253.6 examples/sec; 0.113 sec/batch)
step 3: (37966.0 examples/sec; 0.108 sec/batch)
step 4: (38511.4 examples/sec; 0.106 sec/batch)
step 5: (38554.6 examples/sec; 0.106 sec/batch)
step 6: (32112.4 examples/sec; 0.128 sec/batch)
step 7: (38912.4 examples/sec; 0.105 sec/batch)
step 8: (39377.0 examples/sec; 0.104 sec/batch)
step 9: (38206.2 examples/sec; 0.107 sec/batch)
step 10: (38222.1 examples/sec; 0.107 sec/batch)
step 11: (38757.5 examples/sec; 0.106 sec/batch)
step 12: (38833.1 examples/sec; 0.105 sec/batch)
step 13: (39774.8 examples/sec; 0.103 sec/batch)
step 14: (39795.9 examples/sec; 0.103 sec/batch)
step 15: (37850.5 examples/sec; 0.108 sec/batch)
step 16: (38443.5 examples/sec; 0.107 sec/batch)
step 17: (39194.6 examples/sec; 0.105 sec/batch)
step 18: (39164.0 examples/sec; 0.105 sec/batch)
step 19: (39057.5 examples/sec; 0.105 sec/batch)
step 20: (33268.7 examples/sec; 0.123 sec/batch)
step 21: (39459.7 examples/sec; 0.104 sec/batch)
step 22: (39336.2 examples/sec; 0.104 sec/batch)
step 23: (39207.1 examples/sec; 0.104 sec/batch)
step 24: (39330.5 examples/sec; 0.104 sec/batch)
step 25: (38783.9 examples/sec; 0.106 sec/batch)
step 26: (39038.9 examples/sec; 0.105 sec/batch)
step 27: (39214.2 examples/sec; 0.104 sec/batch)
step 28: (39525.9 examples/sec; 0.104 sec/batch)
step 29: (37209.0 examples/sec; 0.110 sec/batch)
step 30: (38356.7 examples/sec; 0.107 sec/batch)
step 31: (36077.0 examples/sec; 0.114 sec/batch)
step 32: (37143.8 examples/sec; 0.110 sec/batch)
step 33: (35961.1 examples/sec; 0.114 sec/batch)
step 34: (33378.4 examples/sec; 0.123 sec/batch)
step 35: (37830.3 examples/sec; 0.108 sec/batch)
step 36: (36789.5 examples/sec; 0.111 sec/batch)
step 37: (36638.2 examples/sec; 0.112 sec/batch)
step 38: (36848.1 examples/sec; 0.111 sec/batch)
step 39: (36041.4 examples/sec; 0.114 sec/batch)
step 40: (36612.0 examples/sec; 0.112 sec/batch)
step 41: (35623.9 examples/sec; 0.115 sec/batch)
step 42: (37589.3 examples/sec; 0.109 sec/batch)
step 43: (37462.9 examples/sec; 0.109 sec/batch)
step 44: (35823.6 examples/sec; 0.114 sec/batch)
step 45: (35911.8 examples/sec; 0.114 sec/batch)
step 46: (36073.8 examples/sec; 0.114 sec/batch)
step 47: (36930.2 examples/sec; 0.111 sec/batch)
step 48: (36142.9 examples/sec; 0.113 sec/batch)
...
step 99: (36434.8 examples/sec; 0.112 sec/batch)
step 100: (1215.0 examples/sec; 3.371 sec/batch)
step 101: (35952.9 examples/sec; 0.114 sec/batch)
step 102: (38422.5 examples/sec; 0.107 sec/batch)
step 103: (39315.8 examples/sec; 0.104 sec/batch)
step 104: (38989.1 examples/sec; 0.105 sec/batch)
step 105: (39091.4 examples/sec; 0.105 sec/batch)
step 106: (39247.6 examples/sec; 0.104 sec/batch)
step 107: (38009.7 examples/sec; 0.108 sec/batch)
step 108: (38746.7 examples/sec; 0.106 sec/batch)
step 109: (39505.4 examples/sec; 0.104 sec/batch)
step 110: (39340.0 examples/sec; 0.104 sec/batch)
step 111: (39065.0 examples/sec; 0.105 sec/batch)
step 112: (38561.1 examples/sec; 0.106 sec/batch)
step 113: (39109.0 examples/sec; 0.105 sec/batch)
step 114: (39203.7 examples/sec; 0.104 sec/batch)
step 115: (39144.4 examples/sec; 0.105 sec/batch)
step 116: (38317.6 examples/sec; 0.107 sec/batch)
step 117: (33757.5 examples/sec; 0.121 sec/batch)
step 118: (34115.4 examples/sec; 0.120 sec/batch)
step 119: (35671.4 examples/sec; 0.115 sec/batch)
step 120: (35297.2 examples/sec; 0.116 sec/batch)
step 121: (36152.8 examples/sec; 0.113 sec/batch)
step 122: (35780.1 examples/sec; 0.114 sec/batch)
step 123: (35847.1 examples/sec; 0.114 sec/batch)
step 124: (36888.9 examples/sec; 0.111 sec/batch)
step 125: (36946.2 examples/sec; 0.111 sec/batch)
...
```

Comment: Could it be that every `!(step%100)` is the start of a new  epoch, and it is reshuffling the training data and transferring to the GPU anew?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I hope your response helps someone else. However, I left this position almost 2 years ago and haven't touched Tensorflow since.